# Finding a character from a book in C++

Tags: c++, text, find, character, line

I have a problem where I have to find a character from a book and I have to give it's location:

```
page n, line x, character y
```

When we reach a new page, the line number is supposed to reset back to 0 and start again, so:

```
page n+1, line 0, character y
```

So far I am using three for-loops:

```
Outter for-loop: navigate through the characters that I need to find
Middle for-loop: navigate through the lines
Inner for-loop: navigate through the characters in the lines in the book 
                that I need to find the characters in
```

Only way I can think of is if I count the number of '/f' form feed characters i detect to obtain the page number and then somehow reset the line number back to 0 and start counting again. I am confused on how to implement this, as I know you can't really reset the loop counter.

I am kind of stuck in the logic on how to do this? Or do I have to start my program all over again to try another method. Sorry I can't give more specifics, I have been trial-and-error this thing all day and couldn't find a way around it. I don't really want to erase everything and try again. .

Below is a sample code of the program trying to search the phrase "hello world" in a book.txt file containing:

```
he is a man of his
'\f'word. From another 
lord he was a godlike
'\f' figure
```

My current program:

```
#include <iostream>     // Basic I/O
#include <string>       // string classes
#include <fstream>      // file stream classes
#include <sstream>      // string stream classes
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// version 0
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    ifstream book;
    ifstream message;
    vector<char> mContent;

    int pageCount = 0;

    if (argc != 3) {
        cout << "Error: Incorrect number of arguments.";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else if (argc == 3) {
        book.open(argv[1]);
        message.open(argv[2]);
    }
    vector<size_t> randPage;
    vector<string> line = {""};

    size_t i = 0;


    while (getline(book, line[i])) {

        line.push_back(line[i]);
        cout << i << ". " << line[i];

        i++;
    }

    char ch;
    while (message.get(ch)) {
        mContent.push_back(ch);
    }

    vector<char> letter;
    vector<size_t> randLine;
    vector<size_t> randChar;
    size_t o = 0;
    for (vector<char>::iterator m = mContent.begin(); m != mContent.end(); ++m) {
        for (size_t w = 0; w < line.size(); ++w) {

            for (size_t n = 0; n < line[w].size(); ++n) {

                if(n>0)
                if (*m == line[w].at(n)) {

                    letter.push_back(*m);
                    if (line[w].find(12) != string::npos)
                        randLine.push_back(w - w);
                    else
                        randLine.push_back(w);
                    randChar.push_back(n);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (size_t q = 0; q < letter.size(); ++q) {



cout << "\n q" << q << " Letter: " << letter[q] << " can be found in   line  " << randLine[q] << " at column: " << randChar[q] << " page: " << pageCount;

    }


    book.close();
    message.close();
    return 0;

}
```

Sample Output:

```
 q0 Letter: h can be found in line  0 at column: 0 page: 0
 q1 Letter: h can be found in line  0 at column: 15 page: 0
 q2 Letter: h can be found in line  1 at column: 16 page: 0
 q3 Letter: h can be found in line  2 at column: 5 page: 0
 q4 Letter: e can be found in line  0 at column: 1 page: 0
 q5 Letter: e can be found in line  1 at column: 17 page: 0
 q6 Letter: e can be found in line  2 at column: 6 page: 0
 q7 Letter: e can be found in line  2 at column: 20 page: 0
 q8 Letter: e can be found in line  3 at column: 7 page: 0
 q9 Letter: l can be found in line  2 at column: 0 page: 0
 q10 Letter: l can be found in line  2 at column: 17 page: 0
 q11 Letter: l can be found in line  2 at column: 0 page: 0
 q12 Letter: l can be found in line  2 at column: 17 page: 0
 q13 Letter: o can be found in line  0 at column: 12 page: 0
 q14 Letter: o can be found in line  1 at column: 2 page: 0
 q15 Letter: o can be found in line  1 at column: 9 page: 0
 q16 Letter: o can be found in line  1 at column: 14 page: 0
 q17 Letter: o can be found in line  2 at column: 1 page: 0
 q18 Letter: o can be found in line  2 at column: 15 page: 0
```

...

Comment: The approach is fundamentally wrong. The correct approach involves reading the contents of the "book" and scanning through it, just once. As each letter is read, check if it's any of the letters searched for, and make a record of it, it's true. Then, at the end of the book, all the information has been collected and can be shown. This approach, of scanning through the entire contents of the book, for each letter to be searched for, is horribly inefficient.

Comment: _I know you can't really reset the loop counter_ what makes you think this? If you _do_ reset it, you need to make sure there is a valid exit condition as you don't want to keep infinitely resetting it

Comment: I know this will sound like a nitpick, but it will really help the readability of your code and make it seem like you care more, which will motivate us to help you more: make sure you don't have too much vertical whitespace, make sure your indentation is logically consistent (your 2nd for loop is indented more than your 3rd for loop), and please don't use `l` (lower-case `L`) as a variable. It looks too much like `1` (numeral one).

Comment: I think it is better if I redo this in @SamVarshavchik comment. Thank you .

Comment: @SamVarshavchik would I put the loop that reads the book within the loop that reads the message file? Kind want to know which is the better approach for your approach.